# ID первого и последнего custom поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Как внутри цикла `new WP_Query` вывести ID первого и последнего custom поста? Это требуется, чтобы зациклить навигацию `prev` и `next`

Вот код функции без верстки

```
$args = array(
'p' => $postID,
'post_type' => 'portfolio-site'
);

$recent = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post();

    if( get_previous_post (true) ) { 
        $first = get_previous_post()->ID;
    } else { 
        $first =
    };

$prevPost = $first;

    if( get_next_post (true) ) { 
        $last = get_next_post()->ID;
    } else { 
        $last =
    };

$nextPost = $last;
```

Я пробовал использовать `get_boundary_post`, но не удалось заставить её работать. Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось решить задачу вот таким способом:

```
if( get_previous_post() ) { 
        $first = get_previous_post()->ID;
    } else { 
        $argsfirst = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'orderby'     => 'id',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
            'post_type'   => 'portfolio-site'
        );
        $postfirst = get_posts( $argsfirst );
        $first = $postfirst[0]->ID;
    };

$prevPost = $first;

if( get_next_post() ) { 
        $last = get_next_post()->ID;
    } else { 
        $argslast = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'orderby'     => 'id',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            'post_type'   => 'portfolio-site'
        );
        $postlast = get_posts( $argslast );
        $last = $postlast[0]->ID;
    };

$nextPost = $last;
```

Не знаю, правильно ли это, но проблема решена